# Unable to write to directory despite 777 and owned by apache

Tags: php, nginx, file-permissions, fedora, selinux

I am running nginx (as the linux user `apache`) and for some reason the below code sends back an error:

```
clearstatcache(TRUE, $file);
if (!file_exists(dirname($file))) {
    error::server(E_WARNING, sprintf('Log file directory doesn\'t exist: %s', dirname($file)));
    return;
}
if (!is_writable(dirname($file))) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN') {
        // POSIX system, get the user
        $uid  = posix_geteuid();
        $user = posix_getpwuid($uid);
        error::server(E_WARNING, sprintf('Log file directory isn\'t writable by %s (%s): %s', $user['name'], $uid, realpath(dirname($file))));
    } else {
        error::server(E_WARNING, sprintf('Log file directory isn\'t writable: %s', realpath(dirname($file))));
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Log file directory isn't writable by apache (48): /var/www/api/v1/logs
```

The directory is owned by the user `apache` and group `apache` and has the `0777` permission. The OS is Fedora 27 (SELinux enabled) and PHP is running as PHP-FPM 7.2.3.

**My Question:** What could be the cause of PHP not being able to write to that directory?

---

**Note:** I am aware that this is likely a duplicate question, however due to the nature of the question it is difficult to find answers not related to linux user or chmod permissions.

Comment: is_writable(); `Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable`. I guess you should use `is_writable($file)` instead

Comment: I noticed you are using `clearstatcache()` on the file, but not the dirname of the file. So it may be giving you a cached response from when it failed with the dirname. @FelippeDuarte he needs `!is_writable` because he is throwing an error condition if its not. Switching it will throw an error if it IS writeable ;)

Comment: You should also check the SElinux log as it may be SElinux which is blocking the access to said directory, this has happened to me.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That is what the following section of code does after the above, however, the error files are dated so the first one of the day needs to be created by PHP, so I need to check the parent directory as well.

Comment: @IncredibleHat That's true, however it still doesn't fix the issue. Further more, *most* of the time that step isn't needed. PHP updates the stat cache very often, and you really only need to call this function if the file was just modified by PHP.

Comment: @Nelson I suspect you're right; however I am still pretty new to SELinux and I am unsure how to work with it.

Comment: @NicholasSummers  you can start at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337704/selinux-is-preventing-nginx-from-writing-via-php-fpm